# Login Form Invalid username/password

Tags: php, sql, database

I have a login form but even if i type a correct email and password i still get invalid username/password. I'm looking at my code and tried debugging it but i can't seem to find the problem.

- Form

  ```
  <form method="post" action = 'plogin.php'>
      <h2 class="sr-only">Login Form</h2>
      <div class="illustration"><i class="icon ion-ios-navigate"></i></div>
      <div class="form-group"><input class="form-control" type="email" name="email" placeholder="Е-маил"></div>
      <div class="form-group"><input class="form-control" type="password" name="password" placeholder="Лозинка"></div>
      <div class="form-group"><button class="btn btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Најава</button></div><a href="#" class="forgot">Ја заборавивте лозинката? Кликнете овде.</a></form>
  ```
- Form Validation

  ```
  if(!empty($_POST)) {
      include('includes/general.php');
      if(!$connection){
          die("Failed to connect to database ".mysqli_connect_error());
      }
      $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_POST['email']);
      $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_POST['password']);
      $hashedPassword = hash('SHA256', $password);
      $query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = '$email' AND password = '$password'";
      $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query) or die (mysqli_error($connection));
      if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
          $_SESSION = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
          header('location: user.php');
      } else {
          echo "<script>alert('invalid username/password');
              window.location.href= 'login.php';</script>";
      }
  } else {
      header('location: index.php');
  ```

Comment: Why do you hash the password, but then never use that hashed value?

Comment: @KIKOSoftware honest mistake there, but do you know why it doesn't compare them right?

Comment: Your query doesn't return any rows. So, I would `echo` the qeury to see what it looks like. Check it against your database.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware I just did and it returns the hashed password. The email is fine but i get back the hashed password not the one that i need to compare.

Answer (score 0):

You hash the password, but don't use the hash...

```
if(!empty($_POST)) {
    include('includes/general.php');
    if(!$connection){
        die("Failed to connect to database ".mysqli_connect_error());
    }
    $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_POST['email']);
    $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_POST['password']);
    $hashedPassword = hash('SHA256', $password);
    $query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = '$email' AND password = '$hashedPassword'";
    $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query) or die (mysqli_error($connection));
    if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
        $_SESSION = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
        header('location: user.php');
    } else {
        echo "<script>alert('invalid username/password');
            window.location.href= 'login.php';</script>";
    }
} else {
    header('location: index.php');
```

Maybe try the code above

Comment: I just did and It still doesn't compare them right.

Comment: Can you share a screenshot of the database?

Comment: https://imgur.com/UgbFRE3      Here is the empty table. If you want i can give screenshot the whole db